# Chrome settings page doesn't load in headless chrome - Selenium Ruby

Tags: ruby, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, capybara

I'm just playing around with quickly amending JS settings in Chrome on the fly, without installing add ons (company policy).  In browser, when I visit the settings page: "chrome://settings/content/javascript?search=javascript", the settings load fine and I can toggle.

When I try this headless in Chrome, the settings page doesn't render. My headless settings do use --no-sandbox. Not sure if this has any bearing.  Has anyone tried this and overcome it?

I'm using:

- Capybara 3.39,
- Selenium Webdriver 4.14
- Cucumber 9.1.2
- Ruby 3.2.2